# Parsing Text Files with Python 3, Regex and Random Numbers

Tags: python, regex, parsing, random, python-3.x

Here is the input text file I am working with: https://gist.github.com/TestAcc7777/5983147

In the text file, each line after the initial few contains 'CORE X', where X is a number from 1 to 64. Some of the lines containing 'CORE X' also contain either 'V3' or 'V4.

For each value of X, I want to output the lines containing 'CORE X' and that also only contain one of 'V3' or 'V4' - which one to is be decided using a random number generator.

I've written the following in Python 3, and incorporated some regex, to write all lines containing 'CORE X' except those containing the rejected 'V' fragments:

```
import re
import random

tri = open(input("Input File: "))
tro = open(input("Output File: "),'w')

for line in tri.readline():
    for i in [1,65,1]:
        if random.random()>0.5:
            q = 4
        else:
            q = 3
        if re.search(r'CORE\s'+str(i), line):
            if re.search(r'V', line):
                if re.search(r'V'+str(q), line):
                    tro.write(line)
            else:
                tro.write(line)
```

When I run the program however, it seems to finish rather quickly and the output file is empty. I still rather inexperienced with Python and programming in general, so any help in getting my program to help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

```
for line in tri.readline():
```

as:

```
for line in tri:
```

`readline()` returns a line.

`for line in tri.readline()` iterate each character(string) of the first line.

Answer (score 2):

@falsetru beat me too it, your just iterating over the first line:

```
import re
import random


# Using With means we don't have to remember to close the file
# First open the input file
with open(input("Input File: ")) as tri:
    # Open the out file for writing
    with open(input("Output File: "),'w') as tro:  
        # For line in the input file, don't need readlines
        for line in tri:
            for i in [1,2]:
                if random.random()>0.5:
                    q = 4
                else:
                    q = 3
                if re.search(r'CORE\s' + str(i), line):
                    if re.search(r'V', line):
                        if re.search(r'V' + str(q), line):
                            tro.write(line)
                    else:
                        tro.write(line)
```

I had reformatted your code and added some comments, so I thought I would post it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check this sample code

```
import re
import random

tri = open(raw_input("Input File: "))
tro = open(raw_input("Output File: "),'w')

cmp1 = re.compile(r'CORE\s[0-9]+\s+V3')
cmp2 = re.compile(r'CORE\s[0-9]+\s+V4')

m = None
for line in tri:
    if random.random()>0.5:
        m = cmp1.search(line)
    else:
        m = cmp2.search(line)

    if m:
        tro.write(line)
        m = None
```